# From FQL we want to get users current location in php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I want to get my friends which belongs to my city from facebook and for this i use current_location.city.
But its not working... please help me.
Thanks

Comment: there is something in your code

Answer (score 3):

This FQL query works for me.  It returns an array of each user's {uid, current_location} where the current_location includes text of the city that I want.

```
SELECT uid, current_location FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND 'Seattle' in current_location
```

Change 'Seattle' to whatever city you'd like, or use a variable to grab the city name from the current user.

Answer (score 1):

You need user's extended permission for current location. Until user approved current location extended permission you can't retrieve it.

You can check the latest graph api base tutorial from here: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT uid, name, current_location.city 
FROM user 
WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
AND current_location.city in (SELECT current_location.city FROM user WHERE uid = me())
```

Answer (score 0):

The FQL query is simple:

```
SELECT current_location FROM user WHERE uid = ID_HERE
```

The returned value is an array - maybe that's why you're off.

The questions are:

- has the user filled out the location
- do privacy settings permit you to access it

Share some code in your question, and someone might be able to help.

Comment: I got the current_location values in array. But I want only city or only state is it possible??