# Facebook query language. Get all user live in california

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working in facebook Application MVC 4 c# SDK 6

is there any way to get the list of all Facebook User. Either friend or not, who lives in California using Facebook Query Language

Comment: Like @JSuar said, it's not possible to query/search for all the people living in California, beacuse the User's location is a permission-restricted field.

Answer (score 3):

List of your friends who live in California and have it list in their current location.

```
SELECT name, current_location
FROM User 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM Friend WHERE uid1 = me())  
      AND current_location.state = "California"
```

[Test out the query here.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20name,%20current_location%0A%20%20%20%20from%20user%20%0A%20%20%20%20where%20uid%20in%20%28select%20uid2%20from%20friend%20where%20uid1%20=%20me%28%29%29%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20and%20current_location.state%20=%20%22California%22)

I don't think it's possible to pull this information on all Facebook users since the location column is not indexed. [This answer does a good job explaining why searching by location along is not possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5824449/1085891)

Helpful links:

- [how to write an fql query to list friends in a particular location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17717708/1085891)
- [From FQL we want to get users current location in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818931/from-fql-we-want-to-get-users-current-location-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The one word answer is No. But you can get access to users that have made their location public.

see similar question [Facebook API: can I get detailed info about user's location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609781/facebook-api-can-i-get-detailed-info-about-users-location)